# Angle bisector divides the triangle into two triangles. Find the area of one of them.

Tags: geometry, triangles

In $\triangle ABC, AB = 12, AC = 10$.
$I$ is incenter $∠BIC = 105 ^{\circ}$.
 Find area of $\triangle ABD$
where $AD$ is angle bisector.

I've drawn the following figure:
[image: Figure]

Now, $∠IBD + ∠ICB =75 ^{\circ}  $
Hence $∠A=180-150=30^{\circ} $
By law of cosines ,
$BC^2=244-120\sqrt3$
Now , $x+y=12$
$x+z=10$
$y+z=\sqrt{244-120\sqrt3}$

Now I want the length of perpendicular from $A$ to $BC$ .
The first problem is that I can't find it.
The second problem is that I think my algebraic approach is not at all elegant , so can anyone find a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: You can use ^{\circ} for degree instead of deg.

Comment: @AGoogler (1) In your work, if $BC^2=244-120\sqrt3$, then $y+z=244-120\sqrt3$ is not true. (2) The method used by Ajay is the correct way of solving it. The approach he is using is called "bisector theorem".

Comment: @mick Yes , it should be the square root of that. And yes I know about that theorem but didn't use it.

Comment: @Mick Why do you think my method is not correct? I think its very standard and general, in addition gives you the length of the angle bisector easily.

Comment: @Sawarnik By agreeing Ajay's method is correct only means I would have the problem solved the same way. It by no mean of implying other's (including yours) is incorrect. After re-viewing your work, I also agree that it is "very general and standard". Sorry for creating such mis-understanding.

Comment: @Mick Ok, no prob :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether its invertendo - compenendo - invertendo or something else. These answers were intended for me so they are written in the language that I can understand. So if you didn't got something do ask.

[image: Page1]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ajay , your approach is nice too. I like the way you solve the questions - with question in red ink , explanation for each step etc.  It'd so much better if I were like you. I just solve problems with pencil and like doing rough work. How do you manage to be so neat?

Comment: @AGoogler I was thinking the same thing too! Its so neat! I am completely opposite however, I do things in the most haphazard manner and don't write anything unless it isn't obvious.

Comment: I wrote all answers of MPA for future reference. I am the most clumsiest person you would ever find. I just sit anywhere making legs touching walls up, use anything I find for writing even a chalk on floor. So don't be sad It's just for MPA.

Comment: I only write main calculations while solving questions for speed. Accuracy comes by experience. If I have to present it to someone then only I write like this.

Comment: @Ajay Oh, then your presentation has got to be the clearest I have *ever* seen.

Comment: I don't think so my handwriting is not good enough.

Comment: BTW @Sawarnik you appeared for RMO?

Answer (score 1):

We know $\frac{\angle A}{2}=15^{\circ}$.

Now by summing the two areas $(ABD)$ and $(ACD)$ we get $(ABC)$, using the area formula $2\Delta=ac\sin B$, we can write it as:
$$AD\cdot12\sin15^{\circ}+AD\cdot10\sin 15^{\circ}=120\sin 30^{\circ}$$ So, $$AD=\frac{30}{11\sin15^{\circ}}$$
Thus, $(ABD)=\frac12\cdot12\cdot AD \cdot\sin 15^{\circ}= 6\cdot\frac{30}{11\sin15^{\circ}}\cdot\sin 15^{\circ}=\frac{180}{11}$.

Comment: Can you please explain your answer? Which two areas are you summing?

Comment: @AGoogler ABD and ACD. Isnt it obvious? We are using $2A=bc\sin A$.

Comment: Okay got it, Thanks.

Comment: @AGoogler Ok :) Is my final answer correct?

Comment: Yes , It is correct :)

Comment: A more simpler one below.

Comment: Why you were using half angle formula?

Comment: @Ajay He didn't use half angle formula.

Comment: @Ajay There is no half angle formulas, its all very simple. Can you understand the expanded answer? [Your approach is nice too :)]

Comment: Yep no half or double I got confused due to 2A I considered it as A*2 coz I use delta for area.